# Iterating through a list with an if-else block

Tags: python, loops

I have a list `text` which is basically the strings of a table in markdown format, with each row its own item in the list. That is, the list is something like `['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3']`.

I am trying to append each row to a string, and that is easily done, but because of how markdown tables are formatted, the row following the title heading (in my case, `text[0]`) has to have a special kind of formatting (seen below). Below is the code I have tried, but instead of just adding the special formatting after the first row, it does it after every row (I found out why). Other than `if text[0]:`, I've also tried using `if item==text[0]:` but that would give me a `NameError: name 'item' is not defined`. How can I solve this problem?

```
for item in text:
    if text[0]:
        reply_string += item+'\n'
        reply_string += "|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|\n"
    else:
        reply_string += item+'\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
if item == text[0]:
```

will work if `item` is already defined. In your case, it's defined in the `for` loop:

```
for item in text:
    if item == text[0]:
    # ...
```

If you do this, you won't get a `NameError` (at least you won't get the error in these lines).

Comment: Oh man, I just realized that it's just a very silly mistake on my part; nothing to do with the if-else block. But thank you!